# some data from nodejs is not inserting in mongodb?

Tags: html, node.js, database, mongodb, express

So, this is the post request for my register route using express.js. I am printing the newUser object to console. It prints all the information i.e. name, collage, address, encrypted password but it didn't prints the ***phone*** to console why? and also only phone number is not inerting in mongodb database.

```
    app.post("/register", function(req,res){
    
    const newUser=new User({
        name:req.body.fname,
        phone:req.body.ffphone,
        email:req.body.femail,
        callege:req.body.fcallege,
        password:req.body.fpassword
        
    });
    
    console.log(newUser);
    
    newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.send("<h1>Registration done</h1>");
        }
    });            
   

})
```

**It only prints this *output* to console:**

```
{
  callege: 'MIT',
  _id: 60450bd602c55639309f93a1,
  name: 'user1',
  email: 'abc@gmail.com',
  password: '123456'
}
```

why it didn't showing phone attribute? Though I am taking right input from html form.

Comment: Try logging `req.body` and double check whether the phone number shows up within the body (and more specifically, under what property). Just an observation: all of the attributes are prefixed with `f` except for phone which is prefixed with `ff`. That may well be deliberate/necessary, but the point is just double check for spelling/typos.

Comment: looks like you got typo error 
`ffphone`to `fphone` may be ?

Comment: thanks, I made `typo error`. Now its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Schema for your `User` model. You probably forgot to add the phone field to it.

Fields that are not included in the schema will not be inserted into the document, which could be why your phone number is not appearing.

Comment: I created the right user schema, it has all corect feild, it also has phone attribute in it                                    
const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true
    },
    phone:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        minLength:10
    }});

Comment: If you `console.log(req.body)` does phone show up as `ffphone`?, or is it `fphone`?, or not at all?

Comment: not at all, it doesn't prints phone in console,  I pasted the output in above question. plz check that. it doesn't has phone attribute

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't the output I'm referring to. Can you post what is the result of `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: `{
  fname: 'user1',
  femail: 'abc@gmail.com',
  fcallege: 'MIT',
  fpassword: '12345678'
}`  So its not showing fphone no.

Comment: Well if that's the case, you need to show us your frontend javascript code that makes the post equest to `/register` so we can debug it.

Comment: sorry, I made `typo`  mistake, now its working thanks